# Confusion regarding generating self signed certificate for application portal developed using liferay

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, certificates, tomcat, liferay

We have a Application Portal developed using `Liferay` bundled with `tomcat`. There are two application servers running `liferay` and we use `httpd` as a front-end which forwards requests to application server using load balancing . For load balancing in `apache httpd` , we are using `mod_proxy_balancer` .

Now , there is a requirement for us to enable SSL for the application Portal . Initially my plan is to try with `self signed certificate` .

My confusion is whether I need to generate certificate for `httpd` or `tomcat` . Since `httpd` does not serve any content and just forwards request , if I generate self signed certificate for `httpd` , only the HomePage of application portal will be SSL enabled , rest of the Webpages including `Sign In` will not be using SSL. In that case I can generate certificate for `tomcat` so that all webpages are served using `SSL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `httpd` is working as a front-end, then clients connecting to the service will be communicating with `httpd` and not `tomcat`; `httpd` takes care of forwarding the request to `tomcat` and passing the response back to the client.

When you implement SSL then the logical place for doing that is in `httpd`; hence `httpd` is where the SSL processing needs to be done.

Only if clients communicate directly with `tomcat` would it make sense for `tomcat` to do the SSL processing, but then you don't have a load-balanced solution via `httpd`.

Comment: If I add `SSL` for `httpd` , then only the homepage is enabled with SSL , rest of the application pages including `Sign in` are not enabled with `SSL` . How can I enable `SSL` for all the webpages in Application Portal.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense. Is only the homepage load-balanced via `httpd`?

Comment: sorry , my bad . I verified all pages are loaded with SSL

Comment: Example for Liferay 7: https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/installing-liferay-on-linux